maven dependency:list-classes transitive not working with tar.gz dependencies
I want to be able to get a list of all classes that an artifact depends on. The maven-dependency-plugin goal list-classes with parameter transitive set to true does exactly what I need. Except there is an issue when there is a dependency on an artifact with type tar.gz
Let's say I have a dependency tree that looks like this:
org.test:parent:jar:SNAPSHOT
+- org.test:A:jar:SNAPSHOT
|  +- org.test:B:jar:SNAPSHOT
|  - org.test:B:tar.gz:SNAPSHOT
+- org.test:C:jar:SNAPSHOT

If I run mvn dependency:list-classes -DgroupId=org.test -DartifactId=parent -Dversion=SNAPSHOT -Dtransitive=true, there is an error "Couldn't download artifact: error in opening zip file". I took a look at the source code (https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/dependency/ListClassesMojo.java) and it seems to only accept artifacts of type jar.
Is there a workaround to alter the transitive dependencies to exclude artifacts of certain types?

A tar.gz artifact can not be put on the classpath. And will not be used by the JVM in any way... The requestion is why do you have something like that in your project ? Can you show the whole pom file you are trying to analyze?
